# XAML MarkupExtension that knows the path of the xaml file instantiating it

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, markup-extensions

Within an override of MarkupExtension.ProvideValue(), while executing in Design Mode, how do I get the path to the xaml file which instantiated that markup extension? 
 That is, can I know the xaml file instantiating my markup extension, *from* my markup extension, in design mode?

I am creating an augmented version of d:DesignData.  So given file MyControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mns="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=../../../SampleData/SampleDataContext.xaml}"/>
```

When opened in Visual Studio xaml designer, MyControl.DataContext will be assigned the contents of SampleDataContext.xaml, located on the filesystem relative to MyControl.xaml.

I am able to set up the basics of the extension, easy enough:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public class MyDesignDataExtension : MarkupExtension
    {
        public string Source { get; set; }

        public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            var s = new FileStream(Source, FileMode.Open);
            var xamlRoot = XamlReader.Load(s);
            s.Close();
            return xamlRoot;
        }
    }
}
```

However FileStream uses my Visual Studio install path as the base path.  Thus, when I use my design data extension

```
d:DataContext="{mns:MyDesignData Source=../../../SampleData/SampleDataContext.xaml}"
```

I get the exception.  "Could not find the file 'C:/Program Files (x86)/SampleData/SampleDataContext.xaml'.  So I need to use the path to MyControl.xaml, to either update the directory base used, or to generate a fully qualified path from my relative path.

Comment: Does this help? `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` or just using a `ViewModelLocator`for DesignData?

Comment: @Peter no on both counts. From the designer, `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` gets you the path of XDesProc.exe, which is located at the base path I'm trying to avoid. As far as `ViewModelLocator`, that doesn't help what I'm trying to achieve, which is a `d:DesignData`-like markup that can load xaml files relative to the xaml in which the markup was referenced.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `IUriContext` service provided by the `IServiceProvider` that you recieve as the first parameter of the `ProvideValue` method :

```
public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    Uri callerUri = ((IUriContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IUriContext))).BaseUri;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work.  `serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IUriContext))` returns null.

Comment: @PaulSkibitzke Indeed it seems like the `IUriContext` service only exists at runtime and not with the designer. I didn't find any other service that could be useful to you :/ Maybe instead of loading your design data from a .xaml file you could instantiate a C# object directly.